# Add a timeout to getScript()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, timeout, getscript

I'm using the `getScript()` JQuery method but could really do with adding a timeout. Some scripts don't come back as failed for a good 6-8 seconds, which is too long.

Is this possible?

I've searched a bit and no solutions have been forthcoming.

Something like:

```
$.getScript(a + "/myspeed/MySpeedServer/mss/js")
        .done(function() {
            //do stuff
        })
         .fail(function() {
            //do stuff
        });
         .timeout(2000)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$.getScript` is simply a wrapper around `$.ajax()`. Hence, you could use `$.ajax()` with the `timeout` option as below.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "script",
    timeout: 2 * 1000
}).done(function() {
    //do stuff
})
.fail(function() {
    //do stuff
});
```

A note from [the doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/): In Firefox 3.0+ only, script and JSONP requests cannot be cancelled by a timeout; the script will run even if it arrives after the timeout period.

You may also use the `abort()` method as [stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery/446626#446626).

Comment: note that docs have caveats about not all browsers will honor `timeout` for script

Answer (score 0):

Since `getScript` doesn't accept timeout option.
You can use `ajaxSetup` method to set global timeout.

If global timeout isn't applicable you can use

```
$.get({
  url: a + "/myspeed/MySpeedServer/mss/js",
  timeout: 5000, // 5 seconds
  dataType: "script"
});
```